# Selenium + Java Wait For Element To Be Visible

Tags: java, selenium

I'm new to Selenium & Java. What I'm trying to accomplish is to wait for an element to appear on a timeout, and if that element appears before the timeout runs down, then just keep running. The code below will give a `TimeoutException` and stop the rest of the code from running.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("my_element")));
```

Comment: Have you tried try/catch?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way:

```
public boolean isFind(WebElement my_element) {
   try{
      WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
    .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("my_element")));
   }
   catch(TimeoutException exception) {
        return false;
    }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find my way!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help, it took me a bit of playing around with it. Here is the solution I came up with. Hope it helps the next guy. Let me know if I messed something up please, thanks again.

```
    try{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='signup_email']")));

    }catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Complete!");
        return;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(d.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='signup_email']"))));
```